# How do I express "x" from this equation?: $y=x/(x^2+1)$

Tags: quadratics, algebra-precalculus

How do I express "x" from this equation?: $y=x/(x^2+1)$. I am not able to express it.. What I really want to do is to find out values of this function: $f(x)=x/(x^2+1)$ if the domain is R{1,-1}. I have wanted to express "x" and than to solve inequations: $x<-1<x<1<x$ and the values of the function than would be the intersection of the results of those inequations (which is quite a long way to solve it, so if you know anything better..).

Comment: Use the quadratic formula on $yx^2 - x + y = 0$  to get $x$ in terms of $y$.

Comment: I should use discriminant to express "x", right? It seems that the result is $(1+sqrt(1-4y^2))/2y$ and $(1-sqrt(1-4y^2))/2y$

Comment: yes, so you can see $y$ is between $-1/2$ and $1/2$, and you can also solve inequalities you mentioned (by cases if necessary). If you want to see what's going on, use a calculator or computer to look at a graph of the original function .